# When the widgets are destroyed the new ones are placed half way down the application

Tags: python, tkinter

When I destroy the widgets form the first frame I want the next element from the next frame to replace them but they move halfway down the page.  I have no clue why it's happening any idea? the issue is around var_state1 but im not sure. when i put run2 in the for it just deletes one widget instead of all of them.

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter.ttk import *
from time import strftime
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

varp = 0
btn_style=Style()
btn_style.configure('TButton', font =
               ('calibri', 20, 'bold'),
                    borderwidth = '4')

class Frame1(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)


        self.Lab1 = Label(self, text="Check When Complete123:").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        self.Lab2 = Checkbutton(self, text="Turn On Icecream Mashine", command=self.check_plus1).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
        self.Lab3 = Checkbutton(self, text="Turn On Radio", command=self.check_plus1).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
        self.Lab4 = Checkbutton(self, text="Turn On Oven", command=self.check_plus1).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
        self.Lab5 = ttk.Button(self, text="Done", command=self.var_state1, style="C.TButton").grid(row=5, sticky=W, pady=4)

    def check_plus1(self):
        global varp
        if varp <= 3:
            varp = varp + 1

    def var_state1(self):
        global varp
        if varp >= 3:
            print("it workd1")
            for widget in Frame1.winfo_children(self):
                    widget.destroy()
            run2()


class Frame2(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        Label(self, text="Check When Complete:").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        Checkbutton(self, text="Cleen The Tables", command=self.check_plus2).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        Checkbutton(self, text="Fill The Sauces ex: Caramell, Hot Fudge...", command=self.check_plus2).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
        Checkbutton(self, text="Fill Spoons", command=self.check_plus2).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
        Checkbutton(self, text="Deep Clean The Bottem Of The Toppings Freaser", command=self.check_plus2).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
        Checkbutton(self, text="Fill The Toppings", command=self.check_plus2).grid(row=5, sticky=W)
        crl2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Done", command=self.var_state2, style="C.TButton").grid(row=6, sticky=W, pady=4)

    def check_plus2(self):
        global varp
        if varp <= 3:
            varp = varp + 1

    def var_state2(self):
        global varp
        if varp >= 5:
            print("it worked2")
            Close_Day()

def run1():
    MyFrame1 = Frame1(root)
    MyFrame1.pack(expand='true',fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
def run2():
    MyFrame2 = Frame2(root)
    MyFrame2.pack(expand='true', fill='both')
    root.mainloop()

run1()
```

Comment: This code won't run as posted. Please make sure the code you post is runnable.

Comment: it runs for me are you getting an error

Comment: I don't think it's possible for this exact code to work for you. I get the error `NameError: name 'W' is not defined`, which is true. You don't define it and you don't import it. It's easily fixed, but you need to make sure the code you post actually works.